# Centre link with background, without making background take up full width?

Tags: html, css

My link has a background color. I need it to be centred but for its background to not take up the full width. I also cant set a fixed width for the link, as the text is provided by a CMS and will var. Cant this be solved without adding additional HTML?

http://jsfiddle.net/jx3e4/2/

```
<a class="green-button" href="#">Download</a>

<a class="green-button two" href="#">Download</a>

.green-button {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.two {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

EDIT - Sorry, I didnt mention, but there is also text within the same parent div that needs to keep its default text align of left.

http://jsfiddle.net/jx3e4/7/

Comment: i like your "green"! =)

Comment: you want the `.two` to be centered?

Comment: @Cherniv I want to center the link (either one), i used the two class to try out different styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the parent div `text-align:center` and the green button - `display:inline-block`

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jx3e4/14/)**

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear. There is text also within the partent div that needs to be kept at its default left text aligned http://jsfiddle.net/jx3e4/4/

Comment: So you wrap the button in a container with text-align:center - http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jx3e4/14/

Answer (score 0):

Try this..........

**HTML**

```
<div class="links">
<a class="green-button" href="#">Download</a>
    <br />
    <br />
<a class="green-button two" href="#">Download</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.green-button {
    background: none repeat 0 0 blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
}
.links {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/jx3e4/11/)

Comment: Get rid of the `display:block` in the `.two` class.

Comment: Still not working for me. Can you post full code or a fiddle? Thanks